# Is it possible to change the processor core at each iteration in a for loop C++/Qt

Tags: c++, memory, raspberry-pi, real-time, multicore

I'm trying to write to a memory from a raspberry pi. In order to write well I have to respect some delays, however I noticed from an oscilloscope that my writing sequences (which is looped as many times as there are addresses) did not respect sometimes the desired times.

I know that the Raspberry Pi (I use a pi 4) is not very suitable as a real time system, but the writing works well at 90% (on a total of more than 130,000 addresses), only on some addresses where it is written badly. So I guess the raspberry pi while writing is doing other tasks in the background and it uses only one core while running the program, I thought it was due to priorities on tasks that made it not respect the time.

I tried to prioritize the program (program in C++/Qt application) with the nice and renice commands but it didn't really change anything. I also looked at program parallelization with OPEN MP looking to write from all cores but one at a time, but I didn't find much about it.

So I ask the question in the title, if you have an idea about this problem.

Comment: It's probably a better idea having only a dedicated core doing the processing.

Comment: One issue is that there is an overhead incurred when switching cores.  This overhead can slow down your program.  Have you considered *loop unrolling*?  You'll want to do more execution in a loop in relation to the overhead (incrementing index, comparing the index).

Comment: If you are considering, for example, two cores, then divide the effort in half.  For example, Core 1 does the upper half of the addresses while Core 2 does the bottom half.  You could also split by "odd / even", however, this may not be efficient when loading the data caches.

Comment: You *could* call `sched_setaffinity()` every iteration to force the current thread to be migrated to another core, but that would be a really clunky way of creating a delay between iterations.  If you have some required minimum delay, probably better to either `nanosleep` on the current core or just busy-wait in user-space for some delay loop that's long enough in the worst case.

Comment: Isolate a CPU core, set nohz_full and rcu_nocbs for that core. Set CPU affinity for your process, and set a scheduling policy to any f the real time ones (RR, for example). It will ensure that no context switches ever happen on that process (unless you do system calls, which you must avoid). Then the only non-predictable thing left will be caches, DDR latencies and AXI congestion.